# Python venv not creating virtual environment

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtual-environment

I'm trying to create a virtual environment for my current Django project using

```
python3 -m venv env
```

however the command doesn't create any directory with bin/include/lib folders.
What exactly am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: **None** of the answers actually answers the question. They are just workarounds. Check [\[SO\]: Python3.7 venv does not Create Virtual Environment Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885771/python3-7-venv-does-not-create-virtual-environment-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same problem. I was able to get venv working by uninstalling Python and reinstalling it (I'm using the Anaconda distribution). The `py -m venv test` command still doesn't have any output after running it, but now it creates a folder for me and I can activate the test environment.

Answer (score 14):

Sometime system's path environment is not aware of **virtualenv.exe**

**solution:**
install virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
```

run command in the directory where you want virtual environment :

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv
```

Answer (score 9):

I have a Windows 10 machine and had a same problem. It was because I had multiple versions of python. Unknowingly windows had created a python.exe in the WindowsApps folder -

[image]

Then the solution is sometimes:(there is a huge chance that, the old %PATH% got renamed)

```
py -m venv venv
```

This python.exe had a size of 0 kb, so I deleted the python.exe in the WindowsApps folder, opened a new Command prompt and it started working.

Comment: IF you use Anaconda, it is recommended to use a conda environment, not a python virtualenv.

Comment: @pauljohn32 ideally good idea to use conda environment, but sometimes it unavoidable.

Comment: Indeed, do a `del "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Python*.exe"` to cleanup Windows Store's advertisement for their own packages.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone facing this issue now, simply changing the command to start `python` instead of `python3` fixes this

Answer (score 2):

why do you have to write `python3 -m venv env` when you base is installed as python3.6 itself?

Just do `pip install virtualenv` this should install virtualenv package if not already installed, then

`virtualenv envname` this will run and should give you a message like this, I have created a env called `testenv`:

```
C:\Users\Admin\python_projects\venvs>virtualenv testenv
Using base prefix 'c:\\python37'
New python executable in C:\Users\Admin\python_projects\venvs\testenv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

If you get this, it is a success, else do let us know what you get, after this you must `cd` into the `Scripts` folder and then run `activate`

Answer (score 1):

Install and create through:

```
pip install virtualenv

virtualenv <your_virtualenv_name>
```

*Then activate the environment, by going to **./your_virtualenv_name/Scripts** folder and then run:*

```
activate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (works for me)

```
python -m venv C:\<optional-EXISTING-directory-path>\<VENV-name-u-want-2-use>
```

For more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am a bit late to answer the question, but before creating a virtual environment always check if we already have a `.venv` hidden folder

1. Navigate to the directory where we want to create a virtual environment
2. Check if we already have one by `ls -la` this command will show us the hidden folders, as `.venv` will be hidden by default
   [image: Check hidden folder using Terminal/Command prompt]
3. If we do not have the `.venv` folder (name is up to us), then create one by `mkdir .venv` to follow the best convention, in this folder we can create multiple virtual environments
4. Now we can create a virtual environment by `python3 -m venv ./venv/drf`
5. In above folder we have created, inside that we are creating one more folder `drf` (Django Rest Rramework)
   [image]
6. At last to run our virtual environment use `source .venv/drf/bin/activate` by this command we are running the script which is there in bin folder
   [image]

**I hope I was able to explain, as I am also learning**

**Please feel free to edit or make any changes in the post, If something is wrong**

Answer (score -1):

pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
try  to install it and do it again

Answer (score -2):

I just had the similar problem, and I realized changing the path directories names by removing the spaces in the name of the directories helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).