# Python3.7 venv does not Create Virtual Environment Directory

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-3.7, python-venv, virtual-environment

I'm trying to create a virtual environment in windows using:

`python3 -m venv <dir-name>`

When I check the contents of the current directory in cmd after running the above command, I don't see the venv directory show up. The command doesn't throw any errors.

This person seems to have had the same problem:
[Python venv not creating virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117467/python-venv-not-creating-virtual-environment)

But the accepted answer was to re-install python, which didn't work for me. Other answers suggest installing virtualenv instead, but as far as I know that is different from venv, which is recommended for python3.3+

Does anyone know how to solve this issue with venv? I've tried python 3.6 and 3.7

**Edit:** The problem seems to be that the location of python.exe set in PATH is not being used. It is instead using: `C:\Users\GSI\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe`. I'm not sure how to fix my environment variable. Is a restart required? I have quite a few things running but I can restart if it's necessary

**Edit2:** I was asked to post a screenshot of the output of the following commands. As you can see, there is no output when I run them with just "python3". When I run the commands with the full path where the exe is installed, I do get ouptut:

[image]

**Edit 3:** I found a helpful post here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor

Apparently typing "python" into CMD when you don't have python installed/added to the PATH variable opens up the Microsoft store and creates a `python.exe` file in `C:\Users\GSI\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`. I'm guessing I tried executing python code when I first installed python but before I had added the PATH variable.

I followed the instructions in the post to remove the "Application Execution Aliases" for python.exe and python3.exe. That got rid of the exe files in WindowsApps (I wasn't able to manually delete them).

However, now when I type `where python3` in CMD, I get:
`INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`

It seems like it's not picking up my PATH values. I tried restarting my computer but no luck

Comment: I like to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux. Try that as a last result.

Comment: Have you tried typing out the full path, e.g. `python3 -m venv c:\path\to\myenv` ?

Comment: What is the <dir-name> you are using?

Comment: Have you tried `virtualenv <envname> -p python3`? Might need to `pip install virtualenv` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, I tested it several times (*e.g.*: [[SO]: PyWin32 (226) and virtual environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58805040/pywin32-226-and-virtual-environments)). 
And yes, they are 2 **different** kinds of animals:

- [[Python 3.Docs]: venv - Creation of virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
- [[PyPA.VirtualEnv]: Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest).

Example:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059885771>sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> set PY
> PYTHONPATH=e:\Work\Dev\Utils\current
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\python.exe" -c "import sys, venv;print(sys.version);print(venv)"
> 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
> <module 'venv' from 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.07.06\\lib\\venv\\__init__.py'>
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\python.exe" -m venv
> usage: venv [-h] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--clear]
>             [--upgrade] [--without-pip] [--prompt PROMPT]
>             ENV_DIR [ENV_DIR ...]
> venv: error: the following arguments are required: ENV_DIR
>
> [prompt]> time<nul
> The current time is: 21:51:57.12
> Enter the new time:
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.07.06\python.exe" -m venv ".\venv_dir"
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [prompt]> time<nul
> The current time is: 21:52:10.54
> Enter the new time:
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> venv_dir
>
> [prompt]> "venv_dir\Scripts\python.exe"
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> ^Z
>
>
> [prompt]>
> ```

**Notes** (things to pay attention to):

- Make sure that things are actually what you think they are: **use full paths** (**like I did for the *Python* executable**). To see what interpreter is invoked in your case, type **`where python3`** in the console

  - Might also apply this to the environment directory
- Enclose paths in *dblquotes* (***"***${SOME_PATH}**"**), as they might contain spaces (and the command interpreter will interpret the part after the *SPACE* as an argument to the one before)
- Check the command return code
- Check environment variables (*e.g.*: *PYTHONPATH*) that might impact the behavior
- Of course, *Python* should be valid (no errors encountered during installation, no files deleted / modified afterwards, ...)

When all the above checks pass, you should be able to create and use a (*venv* created) virtual environment.

#### Update #0

I took a look at the *URL* added in the question: [[SuperUser]: Typing “python” on Windows 10 (version 1903) command prompt opens Microsoft store](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor) (mentioning @Update, @TusharGautam, @MattJecha, @Ramhound great answers, containing useful info and resources).

Apparently, it is because of the 2 ***App Installer*** related items from ***App execution aliases***. Then I went further, and also installed *Python 3.7* from *Microsoft Store*. 
Both (*App Installer* and *Python 3.7*) place some items (including executables) in "***%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps***". The funny thing is that they are ***0* bytes** sized, and they are neither shortcuts nor *symlinks*. I tend to think they don't actually exist on the filesystem, but are some kind of "mock entries" that *Win* displays and acts as if they would be real (the same thing *MS* did when displaying the *.NET assemblies* (which are basically *.dll* files) as directories in *Windows Explorer*).

In the image below, I chose the 2 boxed items as examples:

[image: Img0]

When checking one, the other gets automatically unchecked, which makes sense as both point to the same "executable" (*python3.exe*).

> ```bat
> [prompt]> :: Python3.7 (python3.exe - installed from Microsoft Store) checked
> [prompt]> dir "c:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\py*"
>  Volume in drive C is SSD0-WIN
>  Volume Serial Number is F2CE-FA29
>
>  Directory of c:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
>
> 20/01/24  12:32                 0 python3.exe
> 20/01/24  12:12    <DIR>          PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0
>                1 File(s)              0 bytes
>                1 Dir(s)  197,737,488,384 bytes free
>
> [prompt]> python3 -c "import sys, os;print(\"VER: {0:}\nEXE: {1:}\nCWD: {2:}\nPyPATH: {3:}\".format(sys.version, sys.executable, os.getcwd(), sys.path))"
> VER: 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 01:54:44) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
> EXE: C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
> CWD: e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059885771
> PyPATH: ['', 'e:\\Work\\Dev\\Utils\\current', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0', 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages']
>
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 0
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: App Installer (python3.exe) checked
> [prompt]> dir "c:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\py*"
>  Volume in drive C is SSD0-WIN
>  Volume Serial Number is F2CE-FA29
>
>  Directory of c:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
>
> 20/01/24  12:35                 0 python3.exe
> 20/01/24  12:12    <DIR>          PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0
>                1 File(s)              0 bytes
>                1 Dir(s)  197,737,291,776 bytes free
>
> [prompt]> python3 -c "import sys, os;print(\"VER: {0:}\nEXE: {1:}\nCWD: {2:}\nPyPATH: {3:}\".format(sys.version, sys.executable, os.getcwd(), sys.path))"
> Access is denied.
>
> [prompt]> :: !!! "This app can't run on your PC" popped up !!!
> [prompt]> echo %errorlevel%
> 5
> ```

As a note, the executable ("*C:\Users\cfati\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe*") is also a "mock entry", the real one is actually located in "***%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps***"

From [[MS.DevBlogs]: Who put Python in the Windows 10 May 2019 Update?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-the-windows-10-may-2019-update) (**emphasis** is mine):

> While Python continues to remain completely independent from the operating system, every install of Windows **will include `python` and `python3` commands that take you directly to the [Python store page](https://www.microsoft.com/ro-ro/p/python-37/9nj46sx7x90p)**.

So, there you go, *python3* **is not actually** *python3* (of course, appplies to *python* as well). The funny thing is that in your case it "worked", while in mine it complained (*ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED*).

**Conclusions**:

- I must insist on **always using the full paths**. That way you are not impacted by changes happening in the *OS* (well, your files might get deleted or corrupted, but then you'd have bigger issues)
- Specifying the full path every time, would soon become very annoying, that's why the ***PATH*** environment variable could / should be used. Of course, this works fine (and significantly improves the experience) in probably *90+%* of the cases, but there are some (for example when other installed *app*s / tools that also ship *Python*, add their *dir*s into *PATH*) where it can trigger funny results

Comment: Using the full path for python.exe is what worked for me - thanks for your help! It's weird because I have the path set up in my PATH environment variable. I tried testing with a PYTHONPATH variable as well - no difference. And I didn't get any errors when running the command. But it works now so thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to `where python3` in the console (I modified the 1st bullet). and also `python3 -c "import sys, venv;print(sys.version);print(venv)"` and post the outputs (maybe include them in the question).

Comment: For `where python3` I'm getting:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe`. So that might explain why I needed the full path to the exe as that's not what my PATH is set to. I didn't get any output for the second command

Comment: It doesn't matter if it wasn't in your path, it was found by Windows and invoked. When creating the environment how long did it take? How did you end up installing *Python* in that location? Didn;t you download the installer from www.python.org? Also, what does `python3 -c "import os;print(os.cwd())"` output? Maybe a screenshot with the console would help.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of some of my console output.
When I tried `python3 -m venv <dir>`, it was instantaneous and there was no result. When I tried with the full path of where the python exe is actually installed, it took about 2 seconds and the venv directory was successfully created.
I did download the installer from python.org. It installed in `C:\Users\GSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`, which is what my PATH is set to, but for some reason it wants to use the exe in the "WindowsApps" location I posted above. I'm not sure what the exe is doing in that location

Comment: There are two files in the "WindowsApps" location: python.exe and python3.exe. When I try to delete them, I get a "file cannot be accessed by the system" error

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're in Admin mode (Windows+X button > PowerShell(Admin) > click YES);
this should take you to

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

move to where you installed your Python. then type the following:

```
python -m venv C:\<your-existing-project-directory>\<venv-name-u-want-to-use>
```

VENV will create that a  directory inside the C:\

For more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html